# Failed to get FirebaseApp instance after migrating to SwiftUI lifecycle

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI app with UIKit AppDelegate and SceneDelegate. This app uses Firestore and Firebase Storage and **everything worked completely fine**.

Then I decided to migrate to SwiftUI lifecycle instead of UIKit AppDelegate and SceneDelegate. But now the app crashes on the launch.

This is the error in the console

```
2020-12-29 22:06:24.737199+0530 App Name[15411:5408005] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRIllegalStateException', reason: 'Failed to get FirebaseApp instance. Please call FirebaseApp.configure() before using Firestore'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x193bcd9d8 0x1a7f36b54 0x104c9d4f4 0x104c9c9dc 0x104d7548c 0x104d75364 0x1045cf314 0x1045cf1f8 0x104570704 0x104570a24 0x19a18cd08 0x104570980 0x104570a38 0x193825568)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRIllegalStateException', reason: 'Failed to get FirebaseApp instance. Please call FirebaseApp.configure() before using Firestore'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I've tried both this

```
import Firebase
import SwiftUI

@main
struct AppName: App {

    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

and this method

```
import Firebase
import SwiftUI

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
}

@main
struct AppName: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

but it's still crashing (same error).

Then I've updated all the pods and I even re-downloaded and replaced the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file. But the result is same.

I have no idea what's wrong here. This app still works fine with UIKit AppDelegate and SceneDelegate.
Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Without more context, it's hard to tell what exactly is the problem, but the error message you see means that some part of your app starts making use of Firebase before FirebaseApp.configure() has been executed. If you're using dependency injection, check your DI setup. Might also be useful to look at your call stack when the app crashes to see who's calling.

Comment: Thanks so much for the comment @PeterFriese. I'm using some view models as environmentObjects and the app crashes because of `let db = Firestore.firestore()` in those view models. So I put `let db = Firestore.firestore()` inside the functions of the view models instead of the common `let db = Firestore.firestore()` outside the functions and now the app works fine.

Comment: Awesome - great to hear you found a solution! It might be useful to post this as an answer to your own question so others who run into the same issue can find your solution more easily.